# Updating mongo docs to convert int to decimal type

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of Mongo docs that have a nested property as type Int32. I want to update all documents in situ by converting that field to a type of Decimal.

This is my code so far

```
var myCollection = 'Items';
var count = 0;

db.getCollection(myCollection).find({}).forEach(item => {
    item.Request.Children.forEach(child => {
        child.Size = {$toDecimal: child.Size};
    });
    
    db.getCollection(myCollection).update({ _id: item._id }, item);
});
```

But I get the error

> Error: field names cannot start with $ [$toDecimal]

Comment: I think you are missing `$set`

Answer (score 0):

[$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/) is an aggregation pipeline operator, you are using it as a value which means you are asking the database to write the hash `{$toDecimal: 42}` as your field value which isn't allowed as document keys cannot start with `$` (since `$` is used for operators).

If you want to read-modify-write each document individually, convert the value to Decimal128 instance in your application. Consult your driver documentation for how to instantiate these values correctly.

Alternatively you can try [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) with [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to perform the conversion in bulk.